# Passing the same model to different views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Problem: We have a Main View and a couple of partial views. Everything uses the same model as the main view. On the submit of Main view, I am trying to render a partial view and trying to pass down the model but only the properties that are getting passed down are the editable fields on the page or view. How can I pass down the other properties?

Current workaround: The partial view needs the other data too to generate a e-mail body but as it is not passed down we are creating hidden fields to pass them down.

**Main View**

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CommonSave", "Common", null, new AjaxOptions
   {
                HttpMethod = "Post",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                //OnSuccess = "submitFormSuccess",
                //OnFailure = "submitFormFailure"
            }, new { id = "commonForm" }))
            {
                <div>
                    <table>                            
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type ="submit" name="Common Save" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
        public class CommonController : Controller
        {      
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                CommonModel model = new CommonModel()
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Test Name"            
                };

                return View("Common", model);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult CommonSave(CommonModel model)
            {
                return PartialView("CommonPartial", model);
            }

            public bool BinderSave(CommonModel model)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
```

On load of the main view(Common) `Index` is called.
Upon submitting the Ajaxform on the Main view, the actionmethod `CommonSave` is called but the model passed to `CommonSave` only contains the `Name` and not the `Id`.

How can we pass that down as well without creating hidden fields or doing anything?
My actual model has a lot of fields which needs to be passed down.

Comment: Unlike ASP.Net WebForms there is no magical way to pass all state between requests. So really the answer is "not possible", but since it is not enough to be a good answer leaving it as comment.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using an ajax form I would use an ajax call and populate the fields on success.  Change your button to a button instead of submit

```
<input type ="button" class="btnSubmit" name="Common Save" />
```

then in your script tag

```
$('.btnSubmit').click(function () { 
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CommonSave", "CommonController")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { Id: $('.Id').val() }
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            //put the partial into a div on the form
            $(".commonForm").html(result);
            //now set the fields on the partial from the model
            $('#EmailName').val('@Model.EmailName');
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: +0: While good suggestion I don't think it addresses main "pass [other not rendered properties of model] down too without creating hidden fields or doing anything" question...

Comment: I agree with your comment about not possible so I thought I would give him a way to work around it

Comment: my solution does address the hidden field concern also since in this scenario they aren't needed.

Comment: Matt thanks for the suggestion but as Alexei said my problem is more on how can i pass down the stateless model instead of creating hidden fields or set the fields as on Success.. my model is going to have bunch of custom objects/ lists of certain object in it too.

Comment: as alexei mentioned it isn't possible.  Since you are passing the model through a post method only the fields that have been put in a for helper will be passed back

Answer (score 0):

I understand the need for partial views and will tell you how I've solved this however each view should have it's own model, it just should.  It's a tenet in the MVVM world:

Anyway, the partials could have a model via a interface.  Define your partial view using a interface as it's model.  For example:

interface:

```
public interface IPhone
{
     string PhoneNumber ( get; set; }
}
```

you model:

```
public class MainModel : IPhone
{

      public string Name
      {
          get {  ... }
          set {  ... }
      }

      public string PhoneNumber
      {
          get {  ... }
          set {  ... }
      }
 }
```

The point is that as long as the model passed to the main view implements the interface (the interface could also define a property that is another model) that the partial view depends on then all you need to do is pass the model to the partial, you may need to cast the model to the interface but technically you shouldn't have to.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Not sure how it would help if the problem is not how to structure code, but mismatch of expectations - ASP.Net MVC does not magically pass whole state between requests. I don't think your suggestion addresses  passing more data between requests without additional work.

Comment: it should, I have used 2 partial views in my main view, the partials all used interface based models for the view.  All data was passed backed.